# Is there a more concise way?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing, taylor-expansion

I am currently trying to prove Taylor's Theorem, this is the proof I am given:

[image: q]

I am finding this very long and hard to follow, can anyone give me a more concise, clear proof?

Thanks

Comment: Be sure not to read the proof of Fermat's last theorem.

Comment: @naslundx sorry, I do not understand, is this proof incorrect?

Comment: No no, I'm sure this proof is right, the point was that the proof of FLT is over 100 pages long :)

Comment: @naslundx: Well, that must be the reason why Fermat could not write it on the border of the page. :-)

Comment: @naslundx oops, I just understood (now I feel silly! :P) I love a long, challenging proof, but I very often finding myself asking if it can be written in a more elegant fashion!

Answer (score 1):

We have by the fundemental theorem of calculus:
$$f(x)-f(a)=\int_a^xf'(t)dt$$
and we integrate by parts we find
$$f(x)-f(a)=-(x-t)f'(t)\Bigg|_a^x+\int_a^x(x-t)f''(t)dt=(x-a)f'(a)+\int_a^x(x-t)f''(t)dt$$
Now if we integrate again we find
$$\int_a^x(x-t)f''(t)dt=-\frac{(x-t)^2}{2!}\Bigg|_a^x+\int_a^x\frac{(x-t)^2}{2!}f^{(3)}(t)dt=\frac{(x-a)^2}{2!}+\int_a^x\frac{(x-t)^2}{2!}f^{(3)}(t)dt$$
and the induction is clear.

Notice that at the $n$ steps we find the remainder on the form
$$R_n=\int_a^x\frac{(x-t)^n}{n!}f^{(n+1)}(t)dt$$
and by the first mean value theorem for integration we find $\xi\in(a,x)$ such that
$$R_n=\frac{(x-\xi)^n}{n!}f^{(n+1)}(\xi)(x-a)$$
and this is the Cauchy form of the remainder or we write the remainder on the form
$$R_n=\int_a^x\frac{(x-t)^n}{n!}f^{(n+1)}(t)dt=f^{(n+1)}(\xi)\int_a^x\frac{(x-t)^n}{n!}f^{(n+1)}(t)dt=f^{(n+1)}(\xi)\frac{(x-a)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$
and this is the Lagrange form of the remainder.